# how to avoid using acpi off for ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, acpi

I am trying to install 16.4.03 on my desktop earlier I had 14.04. 14.04 is working fine.However on the same desktop to use  16.4.03 i need to turn acpi off. How do I get around this?

Comment: Why do you think you need to "turn acpi off"?

Comment: I tried 16.4.1 that works with the normal boot. However when i try 16.04.03 it throws be into ttyl terminal if I don't select the acpi=off setting

Comment: Please [edit] your question whenever you need to add information instead of commenting. Also post your full hardware specs because there must be something else at play.